# AC to DC LED dimmer

Tags: light-fixture, led

Alrighty - I am working on a home project. I know SOME electrical engineering as I have a masters in physics.

I am wanting to install a LED dimmer in my home. The LED dimmer I have found online includes a cool touch screen but works off of DC (http://www.ebay.de/itm/Glas-LED-Dimmer-Controller-fur-Wandeinbau-Wanddimmer-Touch-Panel-Schalter-12-24V-/291127098585?var=&hash=item43c886fcd9:m:mu06bDYAOhxGBEV9J_LNM_g)

With specs:

- Voltage: 12-24V DC
- Power : max . 8A
- Power: max . 96W ( 12V ) / 192W (   at 24V )
- Dimensions LxWxH [ mm ] : approx 86.6 x 86 x 36.5
- Operating temperature: -20 ° C to 60 ° C
- Material: polycarbonate / plastic
- Control via touch panel

Now to work with AC I know I need a transformer. I looked at something like this: http://www.ebay.com/itm/AC-110V-220V-TO-DC-12V-Regulated-Transformer-Power-Supply-For-LED-Strip-Light-/261470580279

Specs:

- Input Voltage: AC 110V/220V ± 20% 47/63Hz
- Output Voltage: 12V DC
- Output Current: 5A
- Working Temperature: 0~40℃

I live in Germany (220 V), and want to dim an IKEA light fixture that has 3 x 6 Watt bulbs with this dimmer. Will this work?

thanks!

Comment: You fail to mention one crucial thing: the IKEA 3 x 6 W light, what kind is that. Does it some with an AC adapter ? The power supply (you call it a transformer but it is more than that) and the dimmer will work together for sure. But you need a LED fixture that works on 12 V DC. Is the IKEA thing 12 V, if it is: it will work.

Comment: No - it is hardwire installed: http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/90262587/ with LED bulbs - anyway to do this?

Comment: @renegade05: do you expect everyone here to know how these things are built and operate?

Comment: @PlasmaHH huh? no... but maybe someone does - hence the question. What a weird thing to say.

Comment: @renegade05 There are 3V DC LED light fixtures, 12V DC LED light fixtures and 220V AC LED light fixtures - and many more. We have absolutely no ***ing idea what particular Ikea LED fixture you have in your mind. What we can tell you is that only 12V DC LED will work with 12V DC supply and 12V DC dimmer.

Comment: ok this is a 220 V AC LED light fixture - anyway to do this with this one? Unrelated: why do people need to leave a snarky comment and make me feel like I am an idiot instead of just asking the specs of the light fixture - like @PlasmaHH comment is pure condescension.

Comment: @renegade05 Absolutely not.

Comment: @renegade05 - You cannot operate a 220V AC LED light fixture with a 12V DC supply  and 12V LED controller.

Comment: GU10 specification lamps are 230V AC

Comment: OK, your chosen fixture does NOT work with 12V so you can forget about using the dimmer and power supply ! A solution would be to use DIMMABLE GU10 LED lamps (not sure IKEA sells these) and a standard 240V dimmer, IKEA sells these.

Comment: now I think this question fits more Home Improvement.

Comment: @renegade05: because you are supposed to bring us the necessary information up front, and not have us pull everything out of your nose.

Comment: @PlasmaHH if I knew everything I need and all relevant information I wouldn't be asking for help. I made a decent attempt to supply everything - if something is missing then a simple question to supply that information is sufficient. You are condescending and not helpful - that is all.

Comment: @renegade05: you are just misunderstanding how this site works, that is all. We are not here to do the research for you. It amazes me that you start your post with bragging about some degree, yet you fail to see that talking about some IKEA lights without in the slightest specifying which one, will not tell anyone anything. In most countries IKEA only sells LED lights anyways, so that leaves everyone with dozens of possibilities of which you might have meant, plus the necessity to research for everyone how they operate...

Comment: @PlasmaHH bragging? I just wanted to point out I know some stuff. I missed the fact that the IKEA light is 220 V AC hardwired - that is it. You could say "hey... what are the specs of the light?" not.. oh what an idiot "do you expect .. blah blah blah" You are just rude. I have no misunderstanding about how this works. Part of my question is asking exactly what information I need to consider and an oversight such as that doesn't merit a snarky comment. Try being nice, and if little oversights like that annoy you, you shouldn't be on a help site.

Answer (score 2):

Mains voltage (110 or 220V) LEDs typically are sophisticated devices with internal power supplies that run low-voltage LEDs. The very point of the internal PSU is to provide stable operation which prevents controlling them with 220V dimmer.

As a rule of thumb, of 220V devices only incandescent bulbs are dimmable. All others (fluorescent tubes, leds) should be treated as not dimmable.

Your 12V PSU and dimmer are designed for 12V LED strips or G4 bulbs (which are also 12V).

Comment: Besides you forgot halogens in your list, there are certain LED bulbs marketed as dimmable. Oh and some nitpick, the nominal EU voltage is 230V ;)

Comment: @PlasmaHH Halogens are just a flavour of "incandescent lightbulbs" :P Yeah, I deliberately skipped dimmable electronics as they're quite rare and clearly advertised as an exception to my "rule". OP started with 220V so I didn't wanted to confuse him more than necessary :)